# Custom Principal reverting to GenericPrincipal on new requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iprincipal

I'm trying to implement a custom principal and custom identity in a .NET MVC website. I've created a custom principal class which inherits from IPrincipal and a custom identity which inherits from IIdentity.

When a user logs in I set both Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.Current.User to my custom principal. When I view either through the debugger the values are set with all the properties.

However once the request is complete and I try and request any other pages both Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.Current.User are of type System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal and not my custom principal.

Do I need to do anything "extra" to get my custom principal out of the thread or HttpContext?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values in `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User` are not persisted between requests, they are rebuilt on each request.  The best place for you to do this is probably in the Global.asax; write a function with the prototype:

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

That should get called after a user is authenticated on each request, which will allow you to set the principal how you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Overridding Principal in:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Instead of

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In Global.asax.cs worked for me in an ASP web application

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand on the accepted answer slightly, hopefully I can save somebody a little bit of time.

In my case, the principal I used contained claims that were populated from the results of an external service, so I wanted to cache the results at login time.

I created a simple cache interface, `IUserPrincipalCache`, and registered it with the MVC `DependencyResolver`.  At login, I build up the principal and add it to the cache.  (Since your implementation may vary, I'll leave all that out.)

I then implemented this in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var cache = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserPrincipalCache>();
        var claimsPrincipal = cache.FindUser(User.Identity.Name);
        if (claimsPrincipal != null)
        {
            Context.User = claimsPrincipal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is important to point out the check for `IsAuthenticated`, since I could bypass the cache check in many cases.  You also may not need to update `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, I guess that depends on how you're using it.